# Adding elements only in first row and first column of a matrix with all elements 0

Tags: python

I am trying to add strings in the first row and first column of a matrix. I created a matrix as below.

```
cation = ['O', 'I', 'N', 'Cl', 'Se', 'P', 'S', 'Br', 'F', 'Te']
anion =['Hg', 'Bi', 'Pd', 'Ni', 'Be', 'Fe', 'pb', 'Mo', 'Co', 'V', 'Au', 'Sc', 'Rb', 'Mg', 'H', 'Na', 'Al', 'Os', 'Ru', 'Cd', 'Li', 'Tl', 'Ca', 'Cu', 'Ba', 'In', 'Pt', 'Ir', 'Ti', 'Tc', 'Ga', 'W', 'k', 'Rh', 'Cr', 'Zr', 'Ta', 'Sn', 'Hf', 'Ag', 'Sr', 'Y', 'Mn', 'Re', 'Nb', 'Zn', 'Cs']

column = len(cation) +1
row = len(anion) +1
mat = [[ 0 for x in range(column)] for y in range(row)]
print(mat)

for x in range(column):  
    for y in range(row): 
        mat[0][x] = [i for i in cation] 
        mat[x][0] = [j for j in anion]
        #print(mat[0][y])
```

I added 1 to the length because by that way I can save all the rows and columns to add other elements inside.

Now I want to add `cation` in the first row and `anion` elements in the first column, so my matrix contains all `cation` in the first row and `anion` in columns.

Can you please provide some feedback on this?

Comment: Could you please provide the exact output you want it to give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the conditions while creating the `mat` itself as follows

```
mat = [[ 0 if x == 0 and y == 0 else cation[x - 1] if y == 0 else anion[y-1] if x == 0 else 0 for x in range(column)] for y in range(row)]
```

or write the above code in a function to avoid confusion.

```
def findElement(x, y):
    if x == 0 and y == 0:
        return 0
    if y == 0:
        return cation[x - 1]
    if x == 0:
        return anion[y-1]
    return 0
mat = [[ findElement(x, y) for x in range(column)] for y in range(row)]
```

complete code is

```
cation = ['O', 'I', 'N', 'Cl', 'Se', 'P', 'S', 'Br', 'F', 'Te']
anion =['Hg', 'Bi', 'Pd', 'Ni', 'Be', 'Fe', 'pb', 'Mo', 'Co', 'V', 'Au', 'Sc', 'Rb', 'Mg', 'H', 'Na', 'Al', 'Os', 'Ru', 'Cd', 'Li', 'Tl', 'Ca', 'Cu', 'Ba', 'In', 'Pt', 'Ir', 'Ti', 'Tc', 'Ga', 'W', 'k', 'Rh', 'Cr', 'Zr', 'Ta', 'Sn', 'Hf', 'Ag', 'Sr', 'Y', 'Mn', 'Re', 'Nb', 'Zn', 'Cs']

column = len(cation) +1
row = len(anion) +1
# you can use either of the following approach
# mat = [[ 0 if x == 0 and y == 0 else cation[x - 1] if y == 0 else anion[y-1] if x == 0 else 0 for x in range(column)] for y in range(row)]
mat = [[ findElement(x, y) for x in range(column)] for y in range(row)]
print(mat)
```

to format the output use following code

```
import numpy as np
print(np.matrix(mat))
```

output is

```
[
['0' 'O' 'I' 'N' 'Cl' 'Se' 'P' 'S' 'Br' 'F' 'Te']
 ['Hg' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Bi' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Pd' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Ni' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Be' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Fe' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['pb' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Mo' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Co' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['V' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Au' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Sc' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Rb' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Mg' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['H' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Na' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Al' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Os' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Ru' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Cd' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Li' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Tl' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Ca' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Cu' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Ba' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['In' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Pt' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Ir' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Ti' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Tc' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Ga' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['W' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['k' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Rh' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Cr' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Zr' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Ta' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Sn' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Hf' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Ag' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Sr' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Y' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Mn' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Re' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Nb' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Zn' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['Cs' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Xpeditions for the explanations. This is the one I was looking.

Answer (score 0):

Inferring what you want to do from your question since you wouldn't reply to the comment, if you want your matrix to look something like this (Lets take a small matrix example so that its easy to format here) -

```
[[0, 'a', 'b', 'c'], 
 ['x', 0, 0, 0], 
 ['y', 0, 0, 0], 
 ['z', 0, 0, 0]]
```

Where `cation = ['a', 'b', 'c']`  and `anion = ['x', 'y', 'z']`
Then you'd do the following -

```
mat = [[0 for x in range(len(cation)+1)] for y in range(len(anion)+1)]
mat[0][1:] = cation
for row, anion_element in zip(mat[1:],anion):
    row[0] = anion_element
```

Comment: Hi Raj, Sorry about that. It was a night so I Slept. I think the way you and xpeditions explained is the one I was looking. Thank you so much for that.